# How to compare row values of two gridviews with dropdownlist column in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have two gridviews. The first one has a dropdownlist. When a user clicks a button named 'Show' data will be displayed on both gridviews where data comes from database. The row data on column with dropdownlist must be compared to the rows on the first column of the second gridview. If they are equal a messagebox will prompt saying that there's no changes and data will not be saved, else if they are not equal modal pop-up will be displayed asking if data are correct.

Below is my code for comparing but it only reads the value of the 1st row in gridview1.

```
 For i = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).FindControl("dropdowncriteria"), DropDownList)
            Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).FindControl("txtreason"), TextBox)


            If ddl.SelectedValue = GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text And txt.Text = GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text Then

                MessageBox("No Changes Made! Nothing will be Saved.")
                Return

            Else

                lblmsg.Text = "Are you sure that all the Data you've Selected/Entered are Correct?"
                mdlpopupmsg.Show()
                Return

            End If

  Next
```

What must be the problem on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only reads the first value (i=0) because the return statements cause the for loop to exit after the first comparison. If you want to compare all the rows you will need a variable to keep track of the result of the if test for each row. Something like this:

```
    Dim hasChanges As Boolean = False
    For i = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        ...
        If ddl.SelectedValue = GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text And txt.Text = GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            hasChanges = True
        End If
    Next
    If hasChanges Then
        MessageBox("Has changes.")
    Else
        MessageBox("No changes.")
    End If
```

Comment: I am having a little problem sir...whenever i removed the condition 'And txt.Text = GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text' it works perfect..But when I add it, it doesn't..

Comment: That depends on the specifics of what you are trying to achieve in your application. A good starting place would be to put a breakpoint on that line and run the program. Then, when the breakpoint is hit, hover the mouse over txt.Text and GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text to see the values , check if the values are what you expect?

Comment: I did what you have suggested sir, and it shows that the condition 'txt.Text' doesn't return anything...

Comment: Is my code for finding the textbox control on Gridview correct sir? this one 'Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).FindControl("txtreason"), TextBox)'

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim itemt As Double 
If (DataGridCart.RowCount() > 0) Then
    For i = 0 To DataGridCart.Rows.Count - 1
        'if itemt as double
        itemt = Val(Trim(txtItem.Text))

        If ((DataGridCart.Rows(i).Cells("Item").Value).Equals(itemt)) Then
                    MsgBox("existing entry")
        End If

   Next

 End If
```